# Show custom fields in shop order woocommerce

Tags: php, forms, woocommerce

I created custom billing fields and have added them to the Admin area using

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );


function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ){
    $billing_complex_address = $order->get_meta('_billing_complex_address'); // Get custom field value
    $billing_complex_name = $order->get_meta('_billing_complex_name');
    $billing_complex_address_inside = $order->get_meta('_billing_complex_address_inside');
    $billing_suburb = $order->get_meta('_billing_suburb');

    if( ! empty( $billing_complex_address || $billing_complex_name) ) {
        
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Title').':</strong><br>' . $billing_title .'</p>';
        
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Complex Address').':</strong><br>' . $billing_complex_address .'</p>';
        
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Complex Name').':</strong><br>' . $billing_complex_name .'</p>';
        
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Complex Address Inside').':</strong><br>' . $billing_complex_address_inside .'</p>';
        
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Suburb').':</strong><br>' . $billing_suburb .'</p>';
        
    }
}
```

I now need these fields to show in the shop_order page when making a manual order so the billing fields show

Comment: _"I now need these fields to show in the shop_order page when making a manual order so the billing fields show"_ - 
Can you clarify what you mean by this? where exactly on the shop page? how would you like to see this displayed?

Comment: Basically the billing address field shows the defaults of Woocommerce, I however have more fields that need to be seen.